# What architecture should I use for my application?

Tags: java, oop

I am creating an application that consist of two types of job managers. I have the following interface:

```
public interface IJobManager {
 public void add(Job job);
 public void delete(Job job);
}
```

With this interface I want to create two types of Managers - one that adds and reads info from file and one that saves it into database.

```
public interface ITransactionJobManager extends IJobManager {
 //some additional functionallity
}

public interface IFileJobManager extends IJobManager {
 //some different functionallity
}
```

So my question is how should I proceed implementing the architecture if my application reads for example an environment variable (or something from `.property` file) and creates single instance of either `TransactionJobManager` or `FileJobManager`.

Comment: what do you except to be the answer? finished code for your application, a summary of possible programming structures, names of possible classes, logical connections and calls? Your question is to broad, unclear and to opinion based to be answered

Comment: I was expecting something like a joker, not code. More like logical connections

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to create a `JobManagerFactory` that creates the required type of job manager depending on the configuration:

```
public class JobManagerFactory {

    public IJobManager createJobManager() {
        // Create the appropriate type of job manager according to the configuration
        return ...;
    }
}
```

See: [Factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

`ITransactionJobManager` and `IFileJobManager` should be an `abstract` class, not an interface. That way, you can define their functionality, and create subclasses of them if you need to specialize more those jobs.